# How can I restore Maps app

Tags: macbook-pro

I would like to know how I can restore my mac Maps App with time machine back up. Maps , although the app opens ,I can only see the grid , either in map or satellite , I can even see the "Pin" drop onto the grid if I enter an address , however  if I try to "report a problem", via the maps sub menu , it tells me I have no internet connection.

Comment: Where did you write this question? Was it on the same computer you have the problem with?

Comment: If so, then it sounds like a firewall issue.

Answer (score 1):

You only see the grid because you don't have an Internet connection, which is why you can't report a problem either. The map information is downloaded from the Internet.